# Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable, when using a custom cross-field validator in reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

The custom sync validator is

```js
export function passwordsValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (form: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const passwordCtrl = form.get('password');
    const repeatPasswordCtrl = form.get('repeatPassword');

    if ((passwordCtrl.dirty || repeatPasswordCtrl.dirty) &&
      passwordCtrl.value !== repeatPasswordCtrl.value) {

      return {passwordsNotMatch: true};
    }

    return null;
  };
}
```

reactive-form defintion:

```js
  this.registerThirdForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      password: ['', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)],
      repeatPassword: ['', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]
    },
      {validators: [passwordsValidator]});
```

I believe this error is because angular assuming I'm providing an async validator, but as you can see, I provided it in the validators property not asyncValidators.

Comment: just wrap your validators into one more array here `[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]`. it doesn't work in your example because AsyncValidator is expected as 3rd param

Comment: It worked, thanks. It was a stupid question!